# Run python scripts from within Django app

Tags: python, django, shell

I'm helping to build a Django app that will interface with a voip phone system, and they've created some scripts to execute when an action is performed (add, update,delete) in order to have parity with the phone system side. They've asked me to pass the parameters to the script like this 
`/var/www/html/om/om_add.sh deviceid filename title`
They've also mentioned to pass the title as a url, using `urllib.quote_plus(title)` 
Lastly, it should occur after each action is executed in the app.
Now, I've heard that executing shell scripts from a Django app is not advised, but wondering if this is a different case? Also, how I can go about doing this, the only way I know how to pass those params is to pass them through a view. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
def post_create(request):
    device = request.session['device']

    if device == 'dummy':
        return render(request,'access_denied.html')

    did = {'device_id': device }
    form= PostForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None,initial=did)


    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        check = Sounds.objects.all().filter(device_id= device).filter(target=instance.target).exclude(target='generic').first()



        if check:
            instance.pk = check.pk
            instance.device_id= device
            instance.save()         
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        else:
            instance.device_id = device
            instance.save()

            dev = instance.device_id
            name = instance.sound.name
            title = urllib.quote_plus(instance.title) 


            os.execv('/var/www/html/ogm/ogm_add.sh', [dev,name,title])

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

    context= {
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'post_form.html',context,)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

executing a shell script has nothing 
to do with django framework it's core python future .

```
import os
os.execv('path' , ['arg'])
```

the arg can be a list or a tuple you can pass it from database or url etc.

the folowing simple is match batter for this purpose

```
from subprocess import call 
sub = call(['ls' , '-l'])
print(sub)
```

the sub contain the output

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So the way I'm trying to implement it may be stupid, but can you possibly check out the code I've added above (within the create view) , specifically after the "else" statement. It seems to work correctly on my end but I'm not sure on how to check if its actually working and running the script